# Can a parametric default be set via another variable in lesscss?

Tags: css, less

When using lesscss is it possible to declare a default parameter via another variable? I've tried it but can't get it to work. Is it actually possible?

The intent here is to set `@button_bg_color` as the default should `@button_gradient_from and @button_gradient_to` not be declared.

```
@button_bg_color: #9cc961;
@button_txt_color: #fff;

@darkened_button_bg_color: @button_bg_color - #2b2b2b;

.branded_button(@from_color: @button_bg_color, @to_color: @darkened_button_bg_color) {
  color: @button_txt_color;
  background-color: @from_color;
  /* FireFox 3.6 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @from_color, @to_color);
  /* Safari4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, @from_color),color-stop(1, @to_color));
}

.button {
  a {
    .branded_button(@button_gradient_from, @button_gradient_to);
  }
}
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Edit: changed to a mixing per this similar post: [are variable mixin names in LESS possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147200/are-variable-mixin-names-in-less-possible) but this fails with the following rendering:

```
.branded_button(@from_color: @button_bg_color {
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color:;
  background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,,);
  background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0,),color-stop(1,));
}
```

Comment: I don't see where '@'button_gradient_from and '@'button_gradient_to variables are defined... if I remove those variables from your .button class it works fine with the predefined mixin values...

Comment: I thought that if '@'button_gradient_from and '@'button_gradient_to weren't defined then the call would be empty and .branded_button() take the default '@'from_color etc?

Comment: No, it will place whatever you enter as a parameter. Since those two variables are not defined, it replaces the default mixin parameters with nothing, but the point is, they get replaced.

Comment: I should explain, the intent here was to have a default to fall back on if the top and bottom gradient variables aren't defined. If I have to define the variables, then there should be no point in defining a fallback. Right?

Comment: Yeah, without the use of some conditional statement, which is not currently possible, I don't think it will work as you would like. So yeah there really wouldn't be a point for defining a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine a global variable in the local scope. Mixin will be invoked with a new value. Outside the local scope the global variable will preserve its value. See this LESS code.

```
/* global variables */
@f-border-width: 4px;
@f-border-style: solid;
@f-border-color: #BE2;

/* default parameters - global variables */
.f-border (
        @width: @f-border-width, 
        @style: @f-border-style,
        @color: @f-border-color
    ) {
    border: @width @style @color;
}

/* using initial value of global variable "@f-border-color" */
.base-1 {
    .f-border;
}

/* changing global variable "@f-border-color" in the local scope */
.extension {
    @f-border-color: #F16;
    .f-border;
}

/* outside of the local scope of ".extension" */
/* global variable "@f-border-color" preserves its value */
.base-2 {
    .f-border;
}
```

It will be compiled into this CSS code.

```
.base-1 {
  border: 4px solid #bbee22;
}

.extension {
  border: 4px solid #ff1166;
}

.base-2 {
  border: 4px solid #bbee22;
}
```

Please, see [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/avrelian/xGS69/).